# authentication and authorisation in wcf for creating a web api

Tags: wcf, web-services, api, rest, wcf-security

I am looking for ways to secure my wcf service.
I have read about message security and transport security.But i am not sure which one to use in my scenario. I want to create a public faced api and in future i want to convert this in Rest api.
What are the general ways to create and secure an web api with wcf

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Application Scenarios](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Application%20Scenarios&referringTitle=Home) section on the [CodePlex WCF Security site](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/), it provides great checklists for a number of different security configurations. The [Guidelines](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guidelines&referringTitle=Home) section may also be useful. I found the site invaluable when looking at the various different options.